# Como retornar variable en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo esta funcion: no se como es la manera de retornar.

```
var getVariablesOriginales=function(nombre){
var objBD = BD();
let res=[];


        objBD.query("select ID_U from usuario u where u.`NOMBRE`=?",[nombre], function(err, rows, fields) {

        objBD.query("SELECT tiempo, variableb FROM tiempos t where t.`ID_U`=? Group By variableb,tiempo",[rows[0].ID_U], function(err, rows, fields) {

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    res.push(rows[i].tiempo);
                };  
        });
        });

    return res;             
}
```

lo que hago para retornar el resultado de esa consulta, copio `row`en una variable auxiliar `res` y luego puedo retornar.

es posible retornar la variable `row` directamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás tratando de conseguir no es posible de la manera en la que lo estas haciendo, básicamente porque la respuesta que quieres retornar es asíncrona mientras que lo que retornas en la función es una respuesta síncrona.

La [asincronía en Javascript](http://blog.amatiasq.com/2014/04/asincronia-y-el-eventloop/) es uno de los conceptos más importantes del lenguaje que deberías conocer.

En este caso, lo que estas intentando hacer es obtener datos de una base de datos (aplicación externa independiente del lenguaje) cuyo tiempo de respuesta es indefinido y susceptible a errores.

Entendamos que sucede:

```
var getVariablesOriginales = function(nombre) {
  var db = BD();
  var res = [];

  // Iniciar consulta a la base de datos:
  db.query("query 1...", [nombre], function(err, rows, fields) {
    // La ejecucion de esta funcion depende del tiempo de respuesta de la bd

    db.query("query 2...", [rows[0].ID_U], function(err, rows, fields) {
      // La ejecucion de esta tambien

      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        res.push(rows[i].tiempo);
      };
    });
  });

  // Cuando se ejecute el siguiente return, el codigo anterior aun no 
  // se ha ejecutado porque la base de datos aun no ha enviado su respuesta.
  return res;
  // Javascript no espera a nadie.
}
```

La solucion para esto es convertir a tu funcion en una funcion asincrona. Javascript te ofrece dos formas:

Usa un [callback](https://fernetjs.com/2011/12/creando-y-utilizando-callbacks/) al estilo de node.js:

```
function queryDB(parameters, done) {
  var db = DB();
  db.query('query 1...', [data], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    db.query('query 2...', [rows[0].something], function(err, rows) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      return done(null, rows);
    });
  });
}

// Uso:
queryDB('something', function(err, res) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

Retorna una [promesa](https://www.azulweb.net/que-son-las-promises-en-javascript-y-como-funcionan/):

```
function queryDB(parameters) {
  var db = DB();

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.query('query 1...', [data], function(err, rows) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      db.query('query 2...', [rows[0].something], function(err, rows) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(rows);
      });
    });
  });
}

// Uso:
var res = queryDB('something');

res.then(function(res) {
  // Manejar la respuesta:
  console.log(res);
});

res.catch(function(err) {
  // Ocurrio algun error...
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: excelente, justo lo que buscaba!!!